# Angular 2 : Modified import Model doesn't update in view

Tags: html, angular, view, angular2-template

I changed my model to fit requirements for using entityframework but the view related to this model can't use the new model which is:

```
export class CV {
    public Id: number;
    public UserId: string;
    public Context: string;
    public Competences: Array<Competence>;
    public Expertises: Array<Expertise>;
    public Formations: Array<Formation>;
    public Missions: Array<Mission>;
}
```

The model before changing is:

```
export class CV {
    public id: number;
    public userId: string;
    public context: string;
    public competences: Array<Competence>;
    public expertises: Array<Expertise>;
    public formations: Array<Formation>;
    public missions: Array<Mission>;
```

Example, I show an object from my console:
[Screenshot from my Chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsAj2.png)

So I want to update the model in my view but I don't know how. I tried different things like ChangeDetectorRef but nothing is working.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: This is case sensitive... you are receiving data e.g like `id`. It's not the same property as `Id`.

Comment: Yeah, I know but that's why I'm asking. Changing the model doesn't change the data in my view @AJT_82

Comment: Yes that is expected behavior. The thing you'd have to do, when receiving the data is to map the values to your new property name instead :)

Comment: How to ? @AJT_82

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you'd use `Interfaces` instead of classes, since at looking at the model, you don't need a class. So change it to an interface instead:

```
export interface CV {
    Id: number;
    UserId: string;
    Context: string;
    Competences: Array<Competence>;
    Expertises: Array<Expertise>;
    Formations: Array<Formation>;
    Missions: Array<Mission>;
}
```

Since your property names do not match the data you are receiving, you need to map the values and set the data with the properties that match your model.

So your service function should look something like this:

```
getData() {
  return this.http.get('the url')
    .map(res => res.json().map((x:any) => 
      Object.assign({Id:x.id,UserId:x.userId,/* Rest of the properties here */})))
}
```

And then in your component you subscribe normally and assign the incoming data as an array of type `CV`.

Comment: Sure, let me know how it goes. This left me thinking a bit, maybe you always have one CV in your array, then we could change the code a bit so that you will not end up with an array with one object, but we could map just that one object, but let me know and if that is the case I'll make the appropriate changes! :)

Comment: Sadly doesn't work : the compilator don't understand this part : Id:x.id (wich is normal since my ts model is exactly the same as the C# one)

Comment: I don't understand. You have uppercase in your model properties... like `Id`, but in JSON you are receiving lower case `id`? That's why I did the `Id:x.id`.

Comment: The error is : Property 'id' doesn't exist in type 'CV'

Comment: I tried for an other entity such as Expertise : `this.http.get(this.actionUrl, this.CVSelection.getCV().Id).map((response: Response) => <Expertise[]>response.json().map((x: Expertise) => Object.assign({
            Id: x.Id, Name: x.Name
        })))`

Comment: That's why I asked the question ^^ because I don't understand either and a lot of my views have this problem

Comment: Where does this error occur, in which file? I mean, that error occurs, if you have some other code somewhere in your app where you are using the old model :) Look at this pic. Dashboard component is not throwing an error, since it has the new model with upper case. But I'm using the model in another component, where I have I'm using the old properties which are in lower case. So make sure that you are using the new model properties everywhere: http://imgur.com/a/FrmN5

Comment: Actually the case is like this : I have a .html, a .component.ts file, a .module file, my model in .ts, a .service.ts file, the C# controller + the model. On my html, if everything is set upperCase, nothing appears but it throw no errors as the console only knows lower case properties. If I set lowerCase on every .ts file, the compilator doesn't work (or send undefined).

Comment: Could you just create a plunker with mock json, since it's impossible to help further unless I can see the actual code.... I'd be happy to take a look if you can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I'll try but since I'm a little newer in this world, I might have issues creating it. Gonna try !

Comment: Like I said, I have problems of other type but here is the plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/Q1vep3ArDWsKDLKGswnh.
Tried to change things to almost copy my project but I missed smthing here. Some body of the service are 1 just for the example

Comment: I'll take a look and let's see if we can figure something out :)

Comment: You had quite many problems with your JSON, so I made a totally new one. You had also services and code that I could not include, such as `Configuration`, since that file was not included in your plunker. I created a bare minimun of your code. Please take a look at it. And I really suggest you start of with just trying to get your code to work with first just getting your CV's in your code, before even including any code such as delete and add CV. When you have gotten the retrieval of cv's (similarily like the plunker), THEN start to add more code like adding a new CV :)

Comment: ... now when you have so much code, it is impossible to pinpoint WHERE the error is, that's why I suggest you first start of with trying to receive all CV's before trying anything else :) Here's the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ERPoFzA3Unuuhl36SVeF?p=preview I also changed using class to interface ;)

Comment: Ok, back on topic. I'll try to do it.
In the meantime tried to search something but didn't found : in your answer this map function has been used for retreive only one object.
But for an array of object ?

Comment: It's not for just one object, as you can see, it's used for an array :)

Comment: So for example, this function :  `this.http.get(this.actionUrl, this.CVSelection.getCV().Id).map(res => res.json().map((x: any) => Object.assign({ Id: x.Id, Name: x.Name })))` 
looks like the one you set before and it's true, it gives me an array of .. the same object : [link](https://puu.sh/vSP6l/baccb3a5a9.png).
I'm taking a lot of your time I think so I'm trying to find on my own, even if your help is precious :D. Thanks again ! :d

EDIT : The number of object in the list is the good one

Comment: Hmm... I assume that the problem is somewhere `getCV().Id`, what is this `Id`, looks strange to me :D I somehow think that you are getting all same data actually with your request? Since I see no error in the `map` Please check the network tab in dev tools and paste the response. Is all objects the same there or are they different?

Comment: As you think in fact the "Id" is not recognized but it's like giving a null body to my function so it is normal that there are 6 object :D (the one recognized is... "id" :D). I have a function GET with no parameters so even if the body is null it runs

Comment: You lost me there :D Still not sure about what you mean. But did you check the response tab in network dev tools to see what you are receiving?

Comment: [Network tab](https://puu.sh/vSPQx/65d0320661.png)
The good result (with expecting that "Id" is null)

Comment: looks good. I don't understand this tho. Now I noticed tho where you gave the code in comment, you are using `{ Id: x.Id, Name: x.Name }` even though it should be `{ Id: x.id, Name: x.name }` but then I don't understand how you even get anything to show in the view since properties are wrong :D I'm running out of ideas here ... hmm.

Comment: Used also `{ Id: x.id, Name: x.name }` but the result is the same :D

Comment: But if you are using `{ Id: x.Id, Name: x.Name }` it shouldn't display *anything* in the view since the properties are wrong, so this seems really strange! Have checked and rechecked and rechecked the plunker, since in there this works perfectly fine...

Comment: Well, at least we tried. I'm doing a workaround by changing all classes first letter in lower Case. I tell you if it runs

Comment: There should not be any problem with the mapping at all, at least I cannot see it. Could you just for the fun of it try and see what happens when we do not use observables and do not modify the data (check plunker). But it really bugs me, since it works in plunker (and in my project) and not your code :D http://plnkr.co/edit/1uajB4IF30Dtjx7vWGlw?p=preview

Comment: Yo, as I had some time and just for the fun I tried what you did before but It didn't run either ^^. I found a workaround meanwhile and I'm not concerned anymore by this problem but ... well ^^'

Comment: This is truly a mystery to me, cannot understand why my solution does not work for you...It really should, I can't see why not. Oh well... :/